# How do I call on information entered into a dialogue box as part of action listener?

Tags: java

I have an action listener attached to a JButton in my program.
When the button is clicked, a dialogue box opens that requests the user to enter a number, then click ok.

This part works fine, what I am having trouble doing is calling upon that number that the user has entered to use as part of an if statement.

Could someone please tell me how I call upon this number that the user has enterd, here is my code so far.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == t1) {
        String Message = "Enter an Amount ";
        String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, Message,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
    if () { // ideally here i would want to say if the user number is bigger
                // than 0 then do this...
    }
}
```

after the changes my code now looks like this

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

```
        if (e.getSource() == t1)
 {
    String Message = "Enter an Amount ";
    String number = 
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                        Message,                          
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);



  if(Integer.valueOf(number) > 0)

{
    String s = a.gettext();
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    repaint();

  new TaxiFrame(Integer.parseInt(s));
```

}

```
  else{}


 }
            else{}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have used some of the code and it has worked so far,
but i now need to refer to that number as part of this expression
String s = a.getText();

i have added the updated code above, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
   //.Convert string to Integer 
   if (Integer.valueOf(number) > 0) {
      //. Do that
   } else {
     //. Otherwise
   }
} catch (NumberFormatException err) {
  err.printStackTrace();
  //.Conversion failed. The user entered a non numeric string
}
```